# Error writing spark dataframe to mysql table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I try to write the content of a spark dataframe into a mysql table. However I always get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 'URL'
```

I am using spark-1.6.0. A Query to the database works without any problem: 
After getting the settings right, I can just run the query and get the results without any problem.

```
val mysqlDriver = "Driver"
val mysqlUsername = "name"
val mysqlPwd = "pwd"
val mysqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://myUrl" 
 val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
Class.forName(mysqlDriver).newInstance

val dataRDD = new JdbcRDD(sc, () =>
  DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlUrl, mysqlUsername, mysqlPwd) ,
  "a query",
  0,
  1000000,
  2,
  r => r.getString("something") + ", " + r.getString("somethingmore") + ", " + r.getString("somethingelse"))
```

However, writing a dataframe to a table does not work:

```
todb.insertIntoJDBC(mysqlUrl + "/db" + "?user=name&password=pwd", "table", false)
```

as this method seems to be deprecated, I also tried:

```
val prop = new java.util.Properties
prop.setProperty("user", mysqlUsername)
prop.setProperty("password",mysqlPwd)
```

tried both of these versions:

```
prop.setProperty("driver", "/somedir/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar")
prop.setProperty("driver", "mysqlDriver")
```

and both of these versions:

```
todb.write.jdbc(mysqlUrl + "/boosting" + "?user=mysqlUsername&password=mysqlPwd", "boosting.user_cluster", prop)
todb.write.jdbc(mysqlUrl, "table", prop)
```

I also put the jar of the driver as one of the `–jars` arguments when starting the spark-shell. Further I tried setting this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setJars(Array("somejar.jar", "/somedir/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar"))
```

Any help on this issue would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correct `driver` class for MySQL is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. Assuming the rest of you settings is correct:

```
prop.setProperty("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```